# Split / extract a Pandas Column of nested tuples into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently working with an .xml file that I have converted into a data frame that looks like so:

[image]

I want to split the Coordinates column into 4 separate columns with the following layout:

```
to_longitude, to_latitude, from_longitude, from_latitude
```

I am attempting to do this with the code below:

```
pd.concat([df[[0]], df[1].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

My question is what am I doing wrong and how can I correct my code to make it work as intended?

Comment: Please include a [`reproducible example`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/4985099) in the post, instead of a image along with the expected output.

Comment: can you post a sample of your dataset as text so that we can replicate please? You can use ```df.to_dict()```

Comment: Execution time comparison of the solutions has been benchmarked below for your reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the string accessor `str[]` to get the values of nested tuples to set up the 4 columns, as follows:

```
df['to_longitude'] = df['Coordinates'].str[0].str[0]
df['to_latitude'] = df['Coordinates'].str[0].str[1]
df['from_longitude'] = df['Coordinates'].str[1].str[0]
df['from_latitude'] = df['Coordinates'].str[1].str[1]
```

**Demo**

```
data = {'Link': ['abd', 'abe'], 
        'Coordinates': [((-4.21, 55.85), (-4.22, 55.86)), ((-4.25, 55.82), (-4.26, 55.83))]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  Link                       Coordinates
0  abd  ((-4.21, 55.85), (-4.22, 55.86))
1  abe  ((-4.25, 55.82), (-4.26, 55.83))

df['to_longitude'] = df['Coordinates'].str[0].str[0]
df['to_latitude'] = df['Coordinates'].str[0].str[1]
df['from_longitude'] = df['Coordinates'].str[1].str[0]
df['from_latitude'] = df['Coordinates'].str[1].str[1]

  Link                       Coordinates  to_longitude  to_latitude  from_longitude  from_latitude
0  abd  ((-4.21, 55.85), (-4.22, 55.86))         -4.21        55.85           -4.22          55.86
1  abe  ((-4.25, 55.82), (-4.26, 55.83))         -4.25        55.82           -4.26          55.83
```

#### Execution time comparison:

**Test data of 40,000 rows**

```
df2 = pd.concat([df] * 20000, ignore_index=True)
```

**Solution 1: Tom Ron's solution**

```
def my_func(record):
    record['to_longitude']=record['Coordinates'][0][0]
    record['to_latitude']=record['Coordinates'][0][1]
    record['from_longitude']=record['Coordinates'][1][0]
    record['from_latitude']=record['Coordinates'][1][1]
    return record

%timeit new_df = df2.apply(my_func, axis=1)
```

**Result:**

```
1min 16s ± 2.19 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Solution 2: SeaBean's solution**

```
%%timeit
df2['to_longitude'] = df2['Coordinates'].str[0].str[0]
df2['to_latitude'] = df2['Coordinates'].str[0].str[1]
df2['from_longitude'] = df2['Coordinates'].str[1].str[0]
df2['from_latitude'] = df2['Coordinates'].str[1].str[1]
```

**Result:**

```
165 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Solution 3: Anurag Dabas' solution**

```
%%timeit
cols=['to_longitude','to_latitude','from_longitude','from_latitude']
out=pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(df2['Coordinates'].values),columns=cols)
#OR
#out=pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df['Coordinates'].values,axis=1),columns=cols)
```

**Result:**
Can't get the benchmarking since got error for both options:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 80000), indices imply (2, 4)
```

**Summary**

Solution 1: Tom Ron's solution

```
1min 16s ± 2.19 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Solution 2: SeaBean's solution

```
165 ms ± 1.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Solution 3: Anurag Dabas' solution

Can't get the benchmarking since got error for large dataset both options

For the first 2 solutions with benchmarking results, SeaBean's solution is **460x times faster** than Tom Ron's solution **(165ms vs 1min 16s)** for 40,000 rows of data.

The faster execution time is contributed by all vectorized Pandas operations (optimized with fast C or CPython codes) used in codes, instead of the slow `apply()` on `axis=1` which under the hood is slow Python looping.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using Pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function -

```
def my_func(record):
    record['to_longitude']=record['Coordinates'][0][0]
    record['to_latitude']=record['Coordinates'][0][1]
    record['from_longitude']=record['Coordinates'][1][0]
    record['from_latitude']=record['Coordinates'][1][1]
    return record


new_df = df.apply(my_func, axis=1)
```